# Ajax/Json MVC table population not working

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to pull the top 10 most recently submitted forms attached to specific userids.

AJAX is not firing and populating my table properly. While debugging, it captures my button click event, and forwards it to ajax but it stops there. The table remains blank and un-populated.

My button click event/ajax call is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#btnLoadRA").click(function () {
    LoadData();
});  

function LoadData() {
    $("#raresults tbody tr").remove();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("getRoofAccessForms", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: '' },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                var rows = "test;";
                $('#raresults tbody').append(rows);
            });
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
            alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
        }
    });
}
```

});

My JsonResult method:

```
   `public JsonResult getRoofAccessForms(string id)
    {
        List<RoofAccessGeneral> raForms = new List<RoofAccessGeneral>();

        int lastFormID = _context.RoofAccessGenerals.Count();

        var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        raForms = _context.RoofAccessGenerals.Where(raGeneral => raGeneral.RoofAccessFormID > lastFormID - 10 && raGeneral.UserID == userid)
            .OrderByDescending(raGeneral => raGeneral.RoofAccessFormID)
            .ToList();

        return Json(raForms, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

` 
My view (just the table):

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="m_widget4_tab1_content">
                    <table id="raresults">
                        <tbody>
                            @* Stuff will be populated here from ajax.*@
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I want output each  record to a row in the table. I'm privy to how to customize this in the ajax loop but I am at a loss for why my testing data is not even being populated when I'm almost certain my Json GET method is pulling from context as I intended (it was grabbing all of the data when debugging). Any suggestions are greatly welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: does showing any exception in your console?

Answer (score 0):

```
function LoadData() {
    $("#raresults tbody tr").remove();
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("getRoofAccessForms", "Home")',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: '' },
        success: function (data) {
            var items = '';
            $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    var rows = "test";
                    $('#raresults tbody').append("<tr><td>" + rows +"</td></tr>");
                });
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
            alert("Message: " + r.Message);
            alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
            alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
        }
    });
}
```

you must add 'tr td' elements when success it will work each and u can write every item.